# Log com debug histórico (IntelliTrace)

Tags: .net, log, debug-histórico, intellitrace

Tenho uma aplicação WPF e estou procurando a melhor maneira de **solucionar** exceções não tratadas. Hoje, quando ocorre uma exceção não esperada, [trato no evento `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/793119/6241184). Lá, gravo o [`Exception.StackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx), assim, na hora de resolver, consigo olhar os métodos que foram chamados, na maioria dos casos, achar a linha onde o erro ocorre não é tão complicado (mas quero melhorar isso)

Ouvi falar ([vídeo - ele reproduz o erro, o arquivo do IntelliTrace é salvo numa pasta, ele abre no VS e consegue depurar](https://youtu.be/uNNpXPCUH2U?t=28m17s)) sobre [gravar dados de debugs históricos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264963.aspx), do IntelliTrace, o que, teoricamente, ajudaria demais na hora da depuração e até em solucionar erros que ocorrem com usuários, mas que não consigo reproduzir em *debug*.

- Como posso coletar informações do IntelliTrace em minha aplicação,
  não estando em *debug*?
- Como posso ler os dados coletados?
- Vale a pena migrar de logs de erros com *stack trace* para IntelliTrace?
- E quanto a performance?

Comment: Não sou muito familiarizado com Itellitrace, mas sei que para produção tem um coletor das informações. Nesta url fala sobre isso https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/hh398365.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As respostas são bem longas, então colocarei os links pra não "poluir" o texto:

1. Como posso coletar informações do IntelliTrace em minha aplicação, não estando em debug?

   - Utilizando o *coletor autônomo IntelliTrace*

> O coletor autônomo IntelliTrace permite coletar dados de diagnóstico IntelliTrace para seus aplicativos em servidores de produção ou em outros ambientes, sem instalar o Visual Studio no computador de destino e sem alterar o ambiente do sistema de destino
>
> Resposta completa: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh398365(v=vs.120).aspx

2. Como posso ler os dados coletados?

   - Você deve abrir o arquivo .iTrace no Visual Studio Ultimate

> Para depurar com o IntelliTrace e percorrer o código, você deve ter os arquivos de origem e de símbolo correspondentes
>
> Resposta completa: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh398365(v=vs.120).aspx

3. Vale a pena migrar de logs de erros com stack trace para IntelliTrace?

   - Depende do resultado que você obtiver depois de configurar/visualizar os Logs, e do impacto no desempenho causado pelo IntelliTrace
4. E quanto a performance?

   - Basicamente, dependerá da configuração que você fizer e do ambiente de produção
   - Dica da MS: *Execute o coletor somente quando você achar que há um problema ou quando você puder reproduzir o problema*
   - Optimizing IntelliTrace Collection on Production Server:

     - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/05/18/optimizing-intellitrace-collection-on-production-server/
     - > Testes mostraram uma redução de 15% no desempenho

Mais informações:

- [Recursos do IntelliTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd572114.aspx)
- [Por que depurar com o IntelliTrace?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd264915.aspx)
- [Configurar sua versão para diagnosticar problemas após a implantação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn449058(v=vs.120).aspx)